# `handleEvent` no longer implemented in Gecko 18 error in submitting a Firefox OS app to marketplace

Tags: web-applications, marketplace, firefox-os

I have developed an app for Firefox OS, it is an packaged app and uses jquery. The jquery javascript file is saved locally in the js directory. When I was submitting to Mozilla Marketplace, I get the following error in the app validator,

```
`handleEvent` no longer implemented in Gecko 18.

Error: As of Gecko 18, objects with `handleEvent` methods may no longer be assigned to `on*` properties. Doing so will be equivalent to assigning `null` to the property.

js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js
2 ... :function(e,t,n){return st.dir(e,"parentNode",n)},next:function(e){return
3 c(e,"nextSibling")},prev:function(e){return c(e,"previousSibling")
4 ... c,f,p;try{if(r&&(i||4===u.readyState))if(r=t,a&&(u.onreadystatechange=st.noop,Gn&&delete Vn[a]),i)4!==u.readyState&&u.abort();else{f={},s=u. ...
//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery.min.map
```

Any help to get this issue sorted is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug tracking this:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=882455